# Can't we obtain observational values for scale factor at different periods in the history of the universe?

Tags: cosmology, astronomy, space-expansion, galaxy-clusters

This may be a stupid question, but it seems to me that we could calculate the value of the scale factor at any stage in the history of the universe by analysing the relationship between recessional velocity and distance in faraway galaxy clusters. Basically, use the same method Hubble used to get to his Hubble's Law: take a base point and then look at how distance to other galaxies varies with their velocities relative to that point? Why can't we do that?

Edit: I realised we can measure the scale factor directly using redshift, but it requires that we know the light travel distance.

Comment: Is your question then: "does Hubble law hold for other galaxies?"

Comment: @caverac Well, I assume it does, seeing as the universe is isotropic

Comment: @caverac alright, if that is my question, can you give me an answer? Any information would be appreciated, because this question is bothering me a lot

Comment: If you start assuming the universe is isotropic and homogeneous, then Hubble's law will hold everywhere, right? Are you looking for an experimental proof of that?

Comment: @caverac Well, if that makes it easier for you to answer, then, yes, let's say that's my question.

Comment: This obviously won't work for the period before star formation. For the period after star formation began, yes -- this is what was done in the 90's with the supernova studies that led to the discovery of dark energy.

Comment: The answer is, I guess, we already do that. But clusters don't form until quite late in the history of the Universe ($z\sim1$, i.e. when the Universe was 6 billion years), so it won't work for high redshifts. At earlier epochs we just use galaxies.

Comment: @BenCrowell We already do that? So why do we have to guess how scale factor varies with time using the LCDM model? And why have we still not confirmed its validity?

Comment: @Pela yeah, by cluster, I actually meant a gravitationally bound system. I haven't realised that clusters first start to form so late into the universe's existence. Anyway, read my response to Ben. This question applies to your comment as well.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that you think that we are able to observe a galaxy, and then measure both the age of the Universe at the time that galaxy emitted the light that we see, _and_ the scale factor at that time. But we're not. We only observe the scale factor (or rather the redshift, but those are related through a = 1/(1+z)). We _then_ use the ΛCDM model to calculate what age it corresponds to (using in this calculation the observed densities of matter, radiation, etc.).

Comment: @pela Actually, that's not quite what I'm saying, but it's quite close. Only knowing the redshifts of two faraway galaxies that are close together would suffice for us to know the value of the scale factor (through the formula that you have given, which would give us the ratio of the two scale factors, and Hubble's Law, providing the ratio of the two scale factors to their derivative, which is assumed to be the same for both. We'd know the age of the universe at that time for certain through light travel distance measured - given we know age of the universe now,

Comment: which could roughly be estimated using the CMB observational limits and upper bounds from other models. That means we'd have a value for our scale factor at each point in the history of the universe

Comment: @Max The thing is, we _don't_ know the age of the Universe at that time, because we _don't_ know the light travel time. We only measure redshift, which only tells us the size of the Universe at the time, relative to now. In principle, the Universe could have been very small until 10,000 yr ago, then suddenly expand by a large factor. Light emitted quite recently, but before that expansion, would then acquire a large redshift. So measuring, say, z = 10, doesn't tell us _when_ it was emitted. To gain that knowledge, we need a model for the expansion history, for which we need the densities.

Comment: @pela We don't know the light travel distance (ltd)? What about standard candles? That give us the ltd? Also, how does the redshift give us any information about the size of the universe? Doesn't it just give us the scale factor at time of emission?

Comment: @pela Sorry, I forgot to mention that we'd also know the derivative of the scale factor at any point as well.

Answer (score 1):

The question of recession velocity vs distance for distant galaxies that the question is posing is not very different than the continuing uncertainties in measuring the current Hubble constant, $H_0$. The former (velocity vs distance) is problematic because the distances measurements to far off galaxies depend on the distance ladder, i.e., determining cosmological distances accurately, whereas the second depends on distance measurements as well, but also on the cosmological model as to how the acceleration/deceleration changed over cosmological times, and the dependence of that on the relative mass and energy densities - i.e. they have some model dependence.

What is fairly clear though is that the dark energy started having enough of a noticeable effect about 5 or 6 billion years ago, based on distance measurements using the distance ladder (cepheid so to supernova and so on). So it is known, from measurements which are semi model-independent (somewhat because little in astrophysics and cosmology can be, you still depend on 'known physics' to get the distance ladder, and sometimes on simplifying assumptions), that the recession velocities are indeed time, or z dependent, and it is modeled by how the scale factor grows when the universe was radiation dominated, matter dominated, or more recently becoming dark energy dominated.

So the answer comes back to how non-model dependent can one measure cosmological distances. The fact is that there are still significant uncertianTies in the measurements of the Hubble constant using the astronomical ladder distances, and using distances estimated by the CMB-related/estimated acoustic density perturbations, and the time delay measurements of gravitationally focused multiple paths in CMB observations. The first measures about 72 Kms/sec/Mpsec, while the latter is around 67 Kms/sec/Mpsec.

Two interesting articles are on the Hubble constant measurement, the first more historical, the second more on the current Hubble constant uncertianTies, where both elucidate how measuring cosmological distances are at the heart of the issue, and the model dependencies. I've seen papers on the issues/uncertianTies of the distance and velocity measurements for different cosmological epochs, and don't remember them to be extremely more accurate, nor to be totally model independent. I don't see that, and neither do cosmologists/astrophysicists, as a big weakness, but more as the normal interplay of theory and measurement in physics. Still, while it is true that we still don't a totally accurate and certain picture of the expansion, any more accuracy in the measurements will refine the models, or find some new physics.

The two references are:

-http://www.pnas.org/content/101/1/8

-http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2017/03/recharged-debate-over-speed-expansion-universe-could-lead-new-physics

-A quick reference to the standard cosmology equations showing the model dependencies, at https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Peacock/Peacock3_2.html

-A reference to the distance ladder, but not much on the most recent attempts to go further, in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_distance_ladder

Comment: I thought we didn't have to use any cosmological models to measure the Hubble constant? For small distances, i.e z<0.5, proper distance is roughly equal to light travel distance - regardless of model chosen (this is true for all models). So where does the uncertainty come from?

Comment: They at least go out to distances where supernovas are used as standard candles, so there's astrophysics assumptions on the physics providing the inherent luminosity. See some of it at https://www.nytimes.com/2017/02/20/science/hubble-constant-universe-expanding-speed.html. Even at a z of 0.5 the model makes a difference, and further out it makes more of one. See the Hubble article witH the history of how much it's varied, and some of the assumptions/methods. See https://www.cfa.harvard.edu/~dfabricant/huchra/hubble/

Comment: alright, you convinced me that there are large uncertainties when measuring distances to faraway objects. However, they are still a fair approximation for actual values of distance. Are the errors so high that when we try to establish the light travel distance, the error bars are so large that uncertainty range includes most cosmological models? It can't be THAT large, right? I mean, the value of the Hubble Constant is more or less agreed upon to be around 72mpckm^-1s^-1 for standard calibrations and around 67mpckm^-1s^-1 for CMB calibrations, right?

Comment: And, actually, the value of the Hubble Constant doesn't even depend on distance measures. We can measure it to a sufficiently good degree of accuracy using CMB.

Comment: So, the fact that the CMB number is significantly different than the distance based measurements is actually a point of controversy. Nobody knows which is the right one, it can't be both, something is wrong in one or both. The CMB numbers and the distance ladder numbers not agreeing is a bad, unexplained, problem. So you see, you do need distance measures, if that can lead to a number. The wrong one may depend on which wrong assumption was made in the physics modeling of one or the other - they both depend on physics models. As I explained in my answer.

Comment: Yes, but how does that have anything to do with measuring light travel distances to further-away objects? I mean, you agree that the problem with Hubble's Constant is not in the error in our actual, physical measurements but rather in our theoretical assumptions. Therefore, we should still be able to measure light travel distances quite accurately. Am I wrong?

Comment: Also, how does measuring Hubble Constant using redshift dependent on any theoretical assumptions? If we assume the scale factor's second time derivative is negligible for small distances, the ratio of redshift to distance would naturally be proportional to the Hubble Constant. We don't need any assumptions (other than negligible second time derivative) - it's just simple maths.

Comment: You don't measure Hubble's constant with redshifts only. You use redshift vs distance, that is why you need the distance ladder. For the CMB use it depends on the whole FLRW, or standard cosmology model. It is not that simple. Take a look at some good cosmology book, eg, Modern Cosmology by Dodelson, pretty much the standard though usually augmented with more recent papers. It'll describe those dependencies and much more. Needs math but nothing huge.

Comment: Yeah, so only distance and redshift; where do theoretical assumptions step in? Also, is itl not true that light travel distance can measured with a very high accuracy?

Comment: No. Distance estimates depends on much physics, like the intrinsic luminosity of something. For high accuracy it makes a difference. On your second point, you can not measure astrophysical distances beyond the distance where parallax can be used. It is all estimation. Anyway, I won't further answer, you can believe what you want.